# Chromedriver.exe remains open in task manager when stopping the debugging in between in Visual Studio'

Tags: c#, selenium

Debug/run test buttons are showing disabled, which I found because the chromedriver.exe is open, how to close the chromedriver.exe through selenium C# code?

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to do? In what way is it not working as expected? What have you tried? Do you have code to show?

Answer (score 3):

I always do quit, dispose and set to null to keep it from leaving processes open:

```
                _driver.Quit();
                _driver.Dispose();
                _driver = null;
```

I recommend against using Kill like the other answer states because it will kill all the chrome processes - which can be adverse if you're running multiple tests in parallel or have other processes using chromedriver running on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Process[] chromeDriverProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver");
foreach (var chromeDriverProcess in chromeDriverProcesses)
{
    chromeDriverProcess.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call Driver.Quit() or Driver.Close() in your Cleanup?

Close() will close the Window and Quit() will end the Process. I've seen a lot of tutorials using "Close", where in my opinion "Quit" would be the better choice.

This will no help you if you are debugging and stop the debugger with code changes or the red square, but it will help if the test completes (either positive or negative)

This method is my cleanup.

```
/// <summary>
/// Cleanup that stops the chrome browser
/// </summary>
[TestCleanup]
public void CloseBrowser()
{
    Driver.Quit();
}
```